# $modal ui-router hitting escape changing state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I want to make my webapp go back to the state it was in when a user hits escape or clicks out of the popop. Right now it only works when a user clicks the okay button which triggers the $scope.close function.

```
.state('rates.rate.runexperiment', {
    url: "/runexperiment",
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal){
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "templates/ExpsResults.html",
            controller: ['$scope', 'ExpsService', function($scope, ExpsService) {

                $scope.expResults = null;

                $scope.getExpResults = function(){
                    ExpsService.getExpResults('1000').get().then(function(response){
                        $scope.expResults = response;
                    });
                };

                $scope.close = function() {
                    $scope.$close(true);
                    $state.go('rates.rate');
                };

                $scope.getExpResults();
            }]
        })
    }]
})
```

so right now the url before they click on the pop up is myendpoint/rates/rate. Then when they click on the pop it opens up and the url is myendpoint/rates/rate/runexperiment. Then when they escape or click out the popup, the window disappears like it should but the state is still myendpoint/rates/rate/runexperiment. It works when the user clicks the okay button and it goes back to myendpoint/rates.

I've tried the onExit feature in the .state but didn't get it to work. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry I haven't had time to get on SO. Working on it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `modal` promise to capture the event when backdrop is clicked or when esc is pressed.

```
   var modalInst = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "templates/ExpsResults.html",
        controller: ['$scope', 'ExpsService', function($scope, ExpsService) {

            $scope.expResults = null;

            $scope.getExpResults = function(){
                ExpsService.getExpResults('1000').get().then(function(response){
                    $scope.expResults = response;
                });
            };

            $scope.close = function() {
                $scope.$close(true);
                $state.go('rates.rate');
            };

            $scope.getExpResults();
        }]
    })


    modalInst.result.then(function () {

    }, function () {//This will be triggered on dismiss/Esc/backdrop click
       $state.go('rates.rate');
    });
```

// Or just use finally to redirect whenevr modal is closed.

```
    modalInst.result.finally(function () { // or .result[finally](
        //Will be triggered always.
        $state.go('rates.rate'); 
    });
```

and remove `state.go` from close function.

Comment: Thanks @PSL It worked. I used the $modal promise to check when esc or event is clicked. I'd like to understand this solution a little deeper, could you elaborate or provide documentation for why this worked? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Garuuk angular modal returns an object with propert called `result` it is a promise. Which internally they resolve/reject when modal is closed. Example:- if you call `close` it will be resolved, if you call `dismiss` it will be rejected so you will go in the catch block of the promise. that is the second callback. When you hit esc or hit backdrop they reject the promise. This can also be used to transfer data between controllers..

Comment: Gotcha, this makes sense as without the promise it's not going anywhere after it gets dismissed. I mean it remains in the current state. Cool thanks!